# Error installing Jupyter with pip3 - Storing debug log for failure

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

To install jupyter in Linux I run the command:

```
   sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

But get this error:

```
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

If I write `pip --version` I get: `pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)`

from `/root/.pip/pip.log` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2401, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2597, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2621, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2721, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2697, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'pytest ==3.2.*', 'at', '*')
```

**EDIT**
I am not using anaconda

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try looking what does the debug log says!?

Comment: I don't know what is that, just copied the final line of the terminal, do you mean the previous lines @PoP ?

Comment: # cat  /root/.pip/pip.log.

Comment: Also the fact that the log is getting stored under ~/root can be a hint that you do not have permissions.

Comment: But I have used sudo, I added the info @PoP

Comment: Looks like you have two versions of Python installed. 3.2 and 3.4.

Comment: For some unexplainable reason it worked. Now jupyter recognizes both versions. I suppose the question must be closed..@PoP

Comment: I don't have enough scores to delete it. You can go ahead and delete the question.

Comment: Can I delete being answered? Here is a related one, you may one to help this newbie: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352018/install-rpy2-returns-an-error @PoP

Answer (score 1):

you have an old version of pip installed I would update pip first using this command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (for windows ) you should have the newest version of pip which is pip 9.0.1 installed after updating pip. After this **If you use anaconda** right click on anaconda prompt(it can be found in search results on start menu by typing Anaconda Prompt). Rightclick this-> run as admin and after that type the following to install jupyter `pip install jupyter` . Avoid using "pip3" on anaconda prompt. **If you don't use anaconda** type `pip3 install jupyter` from command prompt

Comment: This works, the upgrade command install it in /usr/local/bin, so then use /usr/local/bin/pip3..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install jupyter --user
```

Without using sudo. This will store the packages in your home directory, under ~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages if you are using python3.4. Any missing dependencies will also be installed in that directory.