# How to install newer R-packages on Debian Jessie (8.8)?

Tags: r, linux, debian, jupyter-notebook, debian-jessie

On Debian Jessie (8.8), the most up-to-date R package isn't enough for using some Jupyter-notebook functions (like `rpy2`), so I am trying [to get R>=3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352018/install-rpy2-returns-an-error?noredirect=1#comment83706229_48352018) version. The current version is:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
```

Here is an useful link provided by a stackoverflow user: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/, but even with it, I don't know how to get the newer R-version.

Would you help me please?

**EDIT**

Not sure if helps, but here is what I have in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160315-14:54]/ jessie contrib main non-free

## Repositorio oficial de Debian GNU/Linux
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

~

Comment: You make no sense whatsoever.  Debian testing and unstable have R 3.4.3.  If however *you choose to stick with an older distributions such as jessie* then the burden is on you.  And yes. we have "backports" via CRAN.

Comment: But something must be wrong in my configuration, all data I wrote is true @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have Jessie 8.8

Comment: Upgrade to testing, case closed.  OR learn how to get current R onto Jessie.  This is a self-imposed problem.

Comment: I must have written 50+ answers here over the years pointing people to the README at CRAN for Debian and Ubuntu.  Those work.  Read them carefully.  If you are still lost, the r-sig-debian list can help.

Comment: Right, I am just a linux user and do not understand it very much..@DirkEddelbuettel. I understand Jessie 8.8 is too old maybe. I have read CRAN but am not sure about how to install the newer R. That's why the post. Look that I added CRAN link.

Comment: We all had a day when we started, and most of us managed to learn some things.  I can only hope you find the patience to read some of the available documentation.  That worked for thousands of people.  Good questions are welcome here, but you need to do your part.

Comment: That is a good comment.. Just only question: is the link I added right? because that's what i am reading. It seems I need to add `deb http://<favourite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran34/` to repositories @DirkEddelbuettel

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade `r` package from :

**1) Backports repository :** (the `3.3.3` version)

Add the following line to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Save then install `r`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install r-base r-base-dev
```

**2) CRAN repository** (the `3.4.3` version)

Follow the steps described on the [official documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#debian-jessie-oldstable) :

> For a backport of R 3.4.3 to jessie, please add something like

```
deb http://<favourite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran34/
```

> to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` on your computer. You need to substitute `<favourite-cran-mirror>` by one of the mirror URLs listed in the [mirror list](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html).

[**Secure APT**](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#secure-apt)

Before installing the package from CRAN repository , You need to import the singing key released by `Johannes Ranke <jranke@uni-bremen.de>` ([see the secure-apt](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#secure-apt) )

e,g:.

```
echo deb https://mirrors.sorengard.com/cran/bin/ldebian jessie-cran34/ >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
apt-get update
apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```